# RFC 2822 Date Regex

Tags: regex, preg-match

What's the best regex to match an RFC 2822 date?

Basically I would like to match `Date: Sun, 19 Feb 2012 16:25:02 +0000` that appears in some emails I receive, but ideally be language independent.

I did find the below regex online, but not sure how to make month language independent (yet still match the rest) - i believe that month should be 3 characters in the spec, but not totally sure...

```
/^(?:(Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat),\s+)?(0[1-9]|[1-2]?[0-9]|3[01])\s+(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s+(19[0-9]{2}|[2-9][0-9]{3})\s+(2[0-3]|[0-1][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(?::(60|[0-5][0-9]))?\s+([-\+][0-9]{2}[0-5][0-9]|(?:UT|GMT|(?:E|C|M|P)(?:ST|DT)|[A-IK-Z]))(\s+|\(([^\(\)]+|\\\(|\\\))*\))*$/
```

Comment: Your time zone spec is incomplete. For example, my time zone is EET, which is not covered. I'd chicken out and accept any three or four alphabetics rather than try to construct a comprehensive list.

Comment: @tripleee So for that, I'd need to change `(?:ST|DT)` to `(?:ST|ET|DT)`

Comment: Like I wrote, that's most likely still not exhaustive. My recollection is that you can't rely even on the final letter being a T, but it's a long time since I investigated that. By the by, ITYM `[DES]T` but I will repeat, I don't think that's sufficient.  See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_time_zones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @tripleee pointed out, a RFC2822 date will always be English. But if you are parsing dates from a source which is not strictly following RFC2822, and which might use a different language, you will have to identify the set of languages which might be used, and make a single regex which will match any month/day of week name from any of those languages. Afterwards you can use a hash to convert the captured month/day of week names to the internal representation you want to use.

Comment: RFC2822 is always English. Some vendors mistakenly deviate, but that's the spec.

Comment: The programming language is PHP

Comment: @tripleee The spec says it will always be English? Well that is interesting :)

Comment: There is no provision for localization of a header which is intended to be machine-readable.

Comment: Given that the rest of the expression is fairly rigid, you could simply accept any non-space token in the expected places; but then you're left guessing how to translate the month abbreviation to a month number. I have seen Finnish, German, Spanish, French, and Japanese (not necessarily in RFC format; Microsoft, in their wisdom, put localized pseudo-headers in what they arrogantly call forwarded messages).

Comment: @MrJ, what do you think of this suggestion from @tripleee? If you like it, I suggest that tripleee can post it as an answer, you can accept, and I will delete this one.

Comment: @AlexD I like this suggestion :)